# How can I do this replacement in C# with Regex Library?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following problem: I have this text, what i need to do is match with this simple pattern **^(\b(\d{1,2})(.0)?\b)** the start time a supposed 24-hour format.

#### Text in Single String Variable

`1.0  3.53  2.29  31.67
2.0   3.53  2.29  31.67
3.0   3.53  2.29  31.67
4.0   3.53  2.29  31.67
5     3.53  2.29  31.67
6     3.53  2.29  31.67
7     3.53  2.29  31.67
8.0   3.53  2.29  31.67
9     3.53  2.29  31.67
10.0  3.53  2.29  31.67
11.0  3.53  2.29  31.67
12.0  3.53  2.29  31.67
13.0  3.53  2.29  31.67
...`

For example I want to replace **1.0** into **1:00** or add at the end of this match **7** to **7:00**. In other words retrieve the entire text with replacing, something like this:

#### Expected Result

`1:00  3.53  2.29  31.67
2:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
3:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
4:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
6:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
5:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
7:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
8:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
9:00   3.53  2.29  31.67
10:00  3.53  2.29  31.67
11:00  3.53  2.29  31.67
12:00  3.53  2.29  31.67
13:00  3.53  2.29  31.67
...`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have tried with Static method Regex.Replace(text,pattern,"$1:00",RegexOptions.MultiLine), but i dont know how to remove .0 when match is 1.0

Comment: @GrantWinney It's a single string, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a single string every time, you can use the following:

```
String input  = "13.0  3.53  2.29  31.67";
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(\d+)[\d.]*", "$1:00");
//=> "13:00  3.53  2.29  31.67"
```

Comment: Wow so easy like that, it seems it worked. But I have a dude, could you clarify me, please. 

Why regex engine in this match "10.0" is not replaced with "10.0:00". Thank you very much.

Comment: No, I was confused, now I understand that you captured in a group the first two digit, then just added :00. I have to practice more. It was easy. Thank you for making me fall in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest regex, but it should work:

```
((?:^|\s)\d{1,2})(\.0)?(\s|$)
```

Here's a [live example](http://regexr.com/391so).